# I want to post a notification with the facebook php sdk, how do I do this?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authorization, facebook-php-sdk

I have a facebook app and I want to send a notification.

I have the id of the user but can't seem to get a valid access token...

I couldn't find examples that worked online and the [facebook api documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications)  doesn't give examples.

My question boils down to this:

How do I get an access token to do this and which (working) code can I use to perform this action?

S.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your research. Try editing the question more into a question (i.e. drop the downvoted and "sorry" parts), and make the question itself a bit clearer.

Comment: people most likely downvote your question because it does not include what you have tried so far. in other words, there is no code.

Comment: Well, I can't post my non working code if in the end my code worked and I knew that when I was posting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an [app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens) access token, luckily there is a page where you can get it.

-> keep it secret i.e. don't check in in source control, it is directly linked with your app secret...

This is code that works at the time of writing:

replace `{test-user-id}` in the sample with the user id (for instance of a test user)

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php'; // change path as needed

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '',
  'app_secret' => '',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
  ]);

$token = ''; //see rest of answer

$message = 'You have people waiting to play with you, play now!';

$request = $fb->request('post', '/{test-user-id}/notifications?access_token='.$token.'&template='.$message.'&href=test.html');

// Send the request to Graph
try {
  $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error neverthelss: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

echo 'success: ' . $graphNode['success'] . ' error: ' . $graphNode['error'];

?>
```

The $token is obtained from [this tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/) (credits to [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814517/this-method-must-be-called-with-an-app-access-token)).

The page outputs `succes: 1 error:` (and sends the message as a notification to the test user account).

If you click the notification you get directed to `test.html` relative to your app root on your server.

I hope it is useful to others.

Cheers,

S.

Comment: The token is simply appid|appsecret